# You have installed the geocat.datafiles library, but it does not import

Tags: python

I am a user who uses the geocat library.
If you run the Python file after installing it using the

```bash
conda install -conda-forge geocat-datafiles
```

command, you will get the

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geocat.datafiles'

error.
But geocat.viz works fine.
I don't know why this error occurs